# How to echo a command then run it?

Tags: shell, zsh

How to print a command (echo it), then run it in a single command ?

This is useful when you have some alias/function and wants to print what the command is before running the command.

This would be the equivalent of

```
alias mi='echo mvn install; mvn install'
```

The idea is to avoid the repetition of the command (here 'mvn install' is written twice)

Something like:

```
alias echoAndRun='...'
alias mi='echoAndRun mvn install'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you're asking for is probably `set -x` to turn on command tracing.  Remember to turn it off afterward.

```
function showAndTell {
    set -x
    "$@"
    set +x
}
```

(Note that shell aliases are rarely what you want, except in `csh` derivatives where they can simulate functions to some extent because actual shell functions don't exist.)

Given the above function, you also could simply `echo "$@"` within the function; if you want to modify how it displays what it's going to run, you would need to do it that way.

Comment: Echoing "$@" does the trick and was sufficient for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
set -x
```

before the commands are given.